# cx_Oracle, generators, and threads in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, yield, generator, cx-oracle

What is the behavior of cx_Oracle cursors when the connection object is used by different threads?  How would generators affect this behavior?  Specifically...

**Edit**: The original example function was incorrect; a generator was being returned by a sub function, `yield` wasn't used directly in the loop.  This clarifies when `finally` is executed (after `return` does), but still doesn't answer whether a cursor can be used if another thread starts using the connection object the cursor was created from.  It actually seems (in python 2.4, at least), `try...finally` with `yield` causes a syntax error.

```
def Get()
  conn = pool.get()
  try:
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("select * from table ...")
    return IterRows(cursor)
  finally:
    pool.put(conn)

def IterRows(cursor):
  for r in cursor:
    yield r
```

`Get()` is a function called by multiple threads.  The connections are created with the `threaded=False` argument.

I'm wondering...

1. Is thread 1's `cursor` object still usable if thread 2 comes along and uses the same connection object?  If not, what might happen?

The behavior i'm seeing is an exception in cx_Oracle talking about a protocol error, and then a segfault follows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [the docs](http://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/module.html#cx_Oracle.threadsafety): `threadsafety` is, and I quote,

> Currently 2, which means that threads
>   may share the module and connections,
>   but not cursors.

So your "pool of cursors" construct (where one cursor may be used by different threads) seems to be beyond the `threadsafety` level.  It's not an issue of sharing connections (that's OK since you've passed `threaded` properly in the connection's constructor) but cursors.  You may want to store each cursor in `threading.local` after the first time a thread has used it, so that each thread can have its own 1-cursor "pool" (not a key optimization, though: making a new cursor is not a heavy-duty operation).

Wrt your question 2, the `finally` clause executes when the generator object (built by a call to your generator function `Get`) is all done -- either because it's raising `StopIteration`, or because it's being garbage collected (typically because the last reference to it has just gone away).  E.g if the caller is:

```
def imthecaller():
  for i, row in enumerate(Get()):
    print i, row
    if i > 1: break
  # this is the moment the generators' finally-clause runs
  print 'bye'
```

the `finally` executes after (at most) 3 rows have been `yield`ed.

Comment: 1) so, if the `finally` clause executes when the generator is done, the connection is only returned after the cursor is done being used, so it should not be possible for two threads to get the same connection and create cursors from it.
2) The docs make it clear that a cursor can't be shared directly between threads, but its not clear if threads can share a connection and create cursors from it.
3) I'm passing `threaded=False` (I used _without_ in that sentence)

Comment: I should also add that (2) is important because there is other code that does `conn = acquire(); cursor = conn.cursor(); cursor.execute(); row = cursor.fetchone(); release(conn); row['clob_col'].read()`

Comment: I revised my question, the example function i gave was inaccurate.

Comment: Re (2), threads can share a connection if `threaded=True` is used to create it -- otherwise the connection can be used only by the thread that created it.

Comment: I originally thought this answer was wrong, but I believe it was posted against a previous version of the question.